# SQL Query using MySQL sample employee database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem making an advanced (for me) query.

I am trying to get the first name, last name, title, department name, and first and last name of the manager. I am using this SQL in PHP if for some reason you needed to know. I limit to 10 because the database is enormous. I need only the entry for the employees latest data. They have more than one entry because of job promotions, etc.

I included everything I think you would need to understand my problem. Thanks if you can help.

```
mysql>
SELECT DISTINCT employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
titles.title, departments.dept_name, z.first, z.last
FROM employees, dept_emp, departments, titles, 
(
  SELECT employees.first_name AS first, employees.last_name AS last
  FROM employees, dept_emp, dept_manager 
  WHERE 
        employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no 
        AND dept_manager.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
) AS z
WHERE
   employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no 
   AND dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
   AND titles.emp_no = employees.emp_no
LIMIT 10;

+------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| first_name | last_name | title           | dept_name   | first     | last         |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Margareta | Markovitch   |
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Vishwani  | Minakawa     |
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Ebru      | Alpin        |
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Isamu     | Legleitner   |
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Shirish   | Ossenbruggen |
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Karsten   | Sigstam      |
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Krassimir | Wegerle      |
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Rosine    | Cools        |
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Shem      | Kieras       |
| Georgi     | Facello   | Senior Engineer | Development | Oscar     | Ghazalie     |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The database is the employees database from mysql.com:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

```
mysql> desc departments;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dept_no   | char(4)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept_name | varchar(40) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.22 sec)

mysql> desc dept_emp;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept_no   | char(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.20 sec)

mysql> desc dept_manager;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dept_no   | char(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.21 sec)

mysql> desc employees;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.32 sec)

mysql> desc salaries;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| salary    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.34 sec)

mysql> desc titles;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title     | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.60 sec)
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Are you getting an error message? Results different from what you expect?

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for an overview of markdown, and also see the "?" in the tools bar when you are editing a post. Also hover over the icons to see what they do. There is one where you select a block of text to turn into a "code block" (this is done by indenting four spaces). It looks like a pair of braces `{}`.

Comment: I edited your post for readability, accept it. And like Ben Lee said, what is your problem

Comment: My problem is that I can't get the grouping right. It's using Georgi Facello numerous times when I only want the last up to date entry. Before for other queries I was sorting by titles.from_date DESC and LIMIT 1, but I cannot do it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get the first name, last name, title, department name, and first and last name of the manager

Using the theory (but it's probably not optimized if you have large tables), do it step by step. Assuming you have a `$date` PHP variable that contains a date (like the result from `date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')`), or otherwise you may use MySQL's date.

1/ get employees' identity:

```
SELECT
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name
FROM
    employees AS e
WHERE
    1
```

2/ add his/her current title

```
SELECT
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    t.title
FROM
    employees AS e,
    titles AS t
WHERE
    e.emp_no=t.emp_no AND t.from_date<='$date' AND t.to_date>='$date'
```

3/ get his/her current department (from `dept_emp`) and retrieve the department's name

```
SELECT
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name, t.title,
    d.dept_name
FROM
    employees AS e,
    titles AS t,
    dept_emp AS de,
    departments as d
WHERE
    e.emp_no=t.emp_no AND t.from_date<='$date' AND t.to_date>='$date'
AND
    e.emp_no=de.emp_no AND de.from_date<='$date' AND de.to_date>='$date'
AND
    d.dept_no=de.dept_no
```

4/ get the department's manager (from `dept_manager`) and retrieve his/her name (from `employees`)

```
SELECT
    e.first_name AS empFN,
    e.last_name AS empLN,
    t.title AS empT,
    d.dept_name AS dept,
    em.first_name AS manFN,
    em.last_name AS manLN
FROM
    employees AS e,
    titles AS t,
    dept_emp AS de,
    departments as d,
    dept_manager AS dm,
    employees AS em
WHERE
    e.emp_no=t.emp_no AND t.from_date<='$date' AND t.to_date>='$date'
AND
    e.emp_no=de.emp_no AND de.from_date<='$date' AND de.to_date>='$date'
AND
    d.dept_no=de.dept_no
AND
    em.emp_no=dm.emp_no AND dm.from_date<='$date' AND dm.to_date>='$date'
AND
    de.dept_no=dm.dept_no
```

There you can append a `LIMIT` (and an `ORDER BY` probably, you don't know which results will be picked in case of a limit), and/or add in the `WHERE` an `emp_no` for the employee(s) you want to have info about. Not tested though, but it's mainly to let you understand how to build the request.

This is theory, and this request is probably be as heavy to process as the one you wrote. Since you use SQL with PHP, it may be better to retrieve only the primary keys you're interested in, then send short requests to retrieve the information you want. Something like that I mean (using fake functions but the spirit's here):

```
$dateString="from_date<='$date' AND to_date>='$date'";
$qe=query("SELECT emp_no, first_name, last_name, dept_no FROM employees, dept_emp WHERE dept_emp.emp_no=employees.emp_no LIMIT 10 ORDER BY emp_no DESC");
while($r=fetch($qe)) {
  $qt=fetch(query("SELECT title FROM titles WHERE emp_no=".$qe['emp_no']." AND ".$dateString));
  $qd=fetch(query("SELECT dept_name FROM departments WHERE dept_no=".$qe['dept_no']." AND ".$dateString));
  $qm=fetch(query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees AS e, dept_manager AS dm WHERE dept_no=".$qe['dept_no']." AND e.emp_no=dm.emp_no AND ".$dateString));
  //echo/process here
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That does help. Quite a bit actually.

I do want to do a LIMIT and ORDER BY because I will be sorting it for example, List all - using paging limit's of 50 or something, and sorting by one or more departments only...

When I add on ORDER BY empFN LIMIT 10 or something like that, MySQL stalls.

By the way I tried this in MySQL not on the PHP site.

Comment: What do you mean it stalls ? MySQL crashes ? Anything in the logs (especially around the [slow queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) mechanisms: log and configuration) ? Anyway, if your goal is to sort by department (not sure what to understand with your "one or more" part), use `ORDER BY` with a `dept_no`: in any case avoid using a non-indexed field in a `ORDER BY` (and `employees.first_name` is probably not indexed), especially when the request it applies on returns huge results, as it would make it even "more slower" (I mean **very** slow).

Comment: What you can do anyway, as it is a very heavy request to process, is to use [a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) or [a temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) to avoid sending this big bad request every time the page is reloaded. This way, your request from the PHP page will be very fast (essentially something like `SELECT * FROM your_view WHERE 1 ORDER BY some_field LIMIT $offset , 10`). View pros: created once and for all on the server; cons: no index. TempTable pros: can define indexes; cons: created during the connection only.